# Post local image with fb graph api (closed)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I want is:

- share a local image to my fb wall without native fb app installed (not using fb sdk).

What I have tried:

- I'm ok with share url image, status ...
- I tried many threads related to this api: `/me/feed`, `/me/photos/` and also with various kind of fields: `picture`, `source`, `method=photos.upload`...

But it seems that fb changed the way to upload byteArray image through POST or I missed something. Please help me to clarify that professors.

I reference to this document:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads

In this doc, they said that:

```
To specify a photo you can use two methods:

Provide the URL for the photo with the url parameter
Provide a file with the POST request* (how can I do that?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by using those classes:

- LoginManager: request "publish_actions" and get accessToken
- GraphRequest: pass the accessToken to "/me/feed"
- ShareApi: share content normally as ShareDialog